# Error Cannot find module '@babel/core'. but "@babel/core" is installed

Tags: express, babeljs

When I tried to run the server locally to reorganize an old project, an error occurred as in the title. However, @babel/core is already installed in the project, and the same problem is recurring even after deleting and reinstalling.

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "bangba",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "server": "nodemon build/index.js",
    "start": "node build/index.js",
    "stop": "pm2 stop index",
    "build:server": "babel src -d build",
    "build:client": "npx webpack --mode=production",
    "dev:server": "nodemon --exec babel-node src/index.js",
    "dev:client": "npx webpack --mode=development -w"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/somn45/Bangba.git"
  },
  "author": "somn45",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/somn45/Bangba/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/somn45/Bangba#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/node": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.7",
    "@flydotio/dockerfile": "^0.5.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "connect-mongo": "^4.6.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.5.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.5.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "pm2": "^5.2.2",
    "sass-loader": "^12.4.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.66.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1282.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.1",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "express-session": "^1.17.2",
    "express-validator": "^6.14.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.1.4",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.4",
    "multer-s3": "^2.10.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pug": "^3.0.2"
  }
}
```

#### Error Message

```
Error: Cannot find module '@babel/core'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\somn4\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@babel\node\lib\_babel-node.js
```